# Compare one field, Remove duplicate if value of another field is greater

Tags: linux, awk, sed, unique, text-manipulation

Trying to do this at linux command line. Wanting to combine two files, compare values based on ID, but only keeping the ID that has the newer/greater value for Date (edit: equal to or greater than). Because the ID 456604 is in both files, wanting to only keep the one from File 2 with the newer date: "20111015 456604 tgf"

File 1

```
Date     ID     Note
20101009 456604 abc
20101009 444444 abc
20101009 555555 abc
20101009 666666 xyz
```

File 2

```
Date     ID     Note
20111015 111111 abc
20111015 222222 abc
20111015 333333 xyz
20111015 456604 tgf
```

And then the output to have both files combined, but only keeping the second ID value, with the newer date. The order of the rows are in does not matter, just example of the output for concept.

Output

```
Date     ID     Note
20101009 444444 abc
20101009 555555 abc
20101009 666666 xyz
20111015 111111 abc
20111015 222222 abc
20111015 333333 xyz
20111015 456604 tgf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort -ru | awk '!($2 in seen) { print; seen[$2] }'

Date     ID     Note
20111015 456604 tgf
20111015 333333 xyz
20111015 222222 abc
20111015 111111 abc
20101009 666666 xyz
20101009 555555 abc
20101009 444444 abc
```

Sort the combined files by descending date and only print a line the first time you see an ID.

**EDIT**

More compact edition, thanks to Steve:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort -ru | awk '!seen[$2]++'
```

Comment: The less AWKward way: `... | awk '!seen[$2]++'`

Comment: The first one worked perfectly and printed out the rest of the fields. Was using sed -i previously to match and remove using a for loop, but this is much faster since it's not requiring to rewrite the file each time.

The second one only printed out the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you'd like to handle the case were the dates are also duplicated, or even if this case *could* exist. Therefore, I have assumed that by 'greater', you really mean 'greater or equal to' (it also makes handling the header a tiny bit easier). If that's not the case, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27697755/edit) your question.

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    a[$2]=$1
    b[$2]=$0
    next
}

a[$2] >= $1 {
    print b[$2]
    delete b[$2]
    next
}

1

END {
    for (i in b) {
        print b[i]
    }
}' file2 file1
```

Explanation:

Basically, we use an associative array, called `a`, to store the 'ID' and 'Date' as key and value, respectively. We also store the contents of `file2` in memory using another associative array called `b`. When `file1` is read, we test if column two exists in our array, `a`, and that the key's value is greater or equal to column one. If it is, we print the corresponding line from array `b`, then delete it from the array, and `next` onto the next line/record of input. The `1` on it's lonesome will return true, thereby enabling printing where the previous (two) conditions are not met. This has the effect of printing any unmatched records from `file1`. Finally, we print what's left in array `b`.

Results:

```
Date     ID     Note
20111015 456604 tgf
20101009 444444 abc
20101009 555555 abc
20101009 666666 xyz
20111015 222222 abc
20111015 111111 abc
20111015 333333 xyz
```

Comment: You could just set `b[$2]=$0` in the block for after `a[$2] >= $1` and then you wouldn't need to delete anything.

Comment: @Jidder: I see what you're trying to do, but unless I'm mistaken, that won't have the desired effect. This is because I read `file2` first, then `file1`.

Comment: yep, you're right, my bad. Won't that mean if the date is higher in the second file it will be printed twice though ? Not sure if OP would care about that though as they didn't specify.

Comment: @Jidder: Correct; and some code would need to be added to handle that situation. Though, given the sample input, I think that looks unlikely. OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk 'NR==1;FNR>1{a[$2]=(a[$2]<$1&&b[$2]=$3)?$1:a[$2]}
     END{for(i in a)print a[i],i,b[i]}' file file2
```

Compares value in an array to previously stored value to determine which is higher, also stores the third field if current record is higher.
Then prints out the stored date,key(field 2) and the value stored for field 3.

Or shorter

```
awk 'NR==1;FNR>1{(a[$2]<$1&&b[$2]=$0)&&a[$2]=$1}END{for(i in b)print b[i]}' file file2
```